# Get Sub category according to selected category Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a autocomplete text filed for brands and a dropDown for category which is populating through database(SQL Server 2008). here is the code for category dropDown

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
cmd.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader ddlValues;
ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

getCategoryOfBrand.DataSource = ddlValues;
getCategoryOfBrand.DataValueField = "category";
getCategoryOfBrand.DataTextField = "category";
getCategoryOfBrand.DataBind();

cmd.Connection.Close();
cmd.Connection.Dispose();
```

Now I want that when I select brand it automatically set the selected value of category dropDown = selected Brand's category.

this is brands table.

[image: this is brands table.]

Category Table

[image]

code for textChange event of brand text field

```
public void getFallingCategory(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    brandNameUpdated.Text = getBrandForUpdate.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ravissantCon"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string getUser = "SELECT category FROM brands WHERE brandName = '" + getBrandForUpdate.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getUser, con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            getCategoryOfBrand.SelectedValue = sdr["category"].ToString();
        }
    }

    sdr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I got it fixed by myslef :) the problem was that the first letter is capital in category table and small in brand's category column

Comment: I noticed the capitol P as well. You should really be thinking of parameterized queries. Injecting SQL into a query is very risky, especially if you're are not limiting the input. You are just taking the text, not the SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: public String getCategoryByBrand(String brand){ String sql = "SELECT category FROM brands WHERE brandName = @Brand";  
 cmd.CommandText = sql;
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = brand;`
try
{
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
 ddlBrandCategory.SelectedValue = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
 reader.Close();
 con.Close();
}
 catch (SqlException ex)
{
 con.Close();
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

Comment: Thanks Andrew Grinder, Actually this is for testing purpose I am gonna make it through parameters now :), Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have a autocomplete text filed for brands and a dropDown for category which is populating through database(SQL Server 2008). here is the code for category dropDown

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
cmd.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader ddlValues;
ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

getCategoryOfBrand.DataSource = ddlValues;
getCategoryOfBrand.DataValueField = "category";
getCategoryOfBrand.DataTextField = "category";
getCategoryOfBrand.DataBind();

cmd.Connection.Close();
cmd.Connection.Dispose();
```

Now I want that when I select brand it automatically set the selected value of category dropDown = selected Brand's category.

this is brands table.

[image: this is brands table.]

Category Table

[image]

code for textChange event of brand text field

```
public void getFallingCategory(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    brandNameUpdated.Text = getBrandForUpdate.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ravissantCon"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string getUser = "SELECT category FROM brands WHERE brandName = '" + getBrandForUpdate.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getUser, con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            getCategoryOfBrand.SelectedValue = sdr["category"].ToString();
        }
    }

    sdr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```